# success or successes? Which is natural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

All **success** with no failure often **leads** to a person to an arrogance.

All **successes** with no failures often **lead** to a person to an arrogance.

Two sentences are both correct or one of them is wrong?
If two both are possible,  how they are different?

Comment: Singular or plural, it makes no difference to the ultimate meaning. But it should be "... often lead a person to arrogance," **not**  "...lead *to* a person to *an* arrogance."

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the plural of success is also **success**.

"**Successes**" can be used too, though, and is used to specify that there are different kind of successes for that person. ([Source](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/success.html))

So, the usage depends on what meaning you are trying to deliver.

On the side note, arrogance is not countable, hence don't use the article "*an*" with it.
 Also, you are using "*to*" twice for "leads", so avoid that, too.

> All success with no failure often leads a person to arrogance.